# Kill a running process like a webserver inside a Docker container without killing the container

Tags: docker

i want to kill a running process like a Django webserver inside a Docker container without killing the container itself but for some reason if i do `docker exec -it <container> ps -aux` and then `docker exec <container> kill <pid>` it will kill my docker instance and i don't want that.

How can i address this issue?

Comment: maybe you should use supervisor,s6,daemon-tools or any process manager, but I wonder if the process manager will not restart the killed process, the doc for supervisor https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/, why not restart the container, if Django is your only process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can go: `docker exec -it <container> bash` once inside the container you can then `kill <pid>`.  This will kill the process but keep the container running **unless** this is the process the container was started with.

Comment: how can i make it so the process i am using is not the one that starts the container using docker-compose.yml ??

Comment: I would make a bash script called dockerentrypoint.sh and execute the process you want to kill in the background and then run /bin/bash in the foreground.  This will let you go into the container and keep it running if you kill that process.  This is not best practice though since Docker is built around running one process in the foreground.

Comment: for my specific problem i ended up adding `command: bash -c "while true; do echo 'Hit CTRL+C'; sleep 1; done"` to the yml and then i was able to start the process i wanted inside and kill it as well. will have a better look at your solution. thanks